# python - putting list items in a queue

Tags: python

I have following code:

```
self.queryQ = Queue.Queue()
queries = self.getQueries()  # returns list

for query in queries:
  self.queryQ.put(query)
```

Is there a better way for following code? Please provide pointers.

Comment: The docs (http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) do not state another way besides repeatedly calling the `put` method.

Comment: doesn't this belong on codereview?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use list comprehension, it's faster.

```
list = [self.queryQ.put(query) for query in queries]
```

Comment: Outside of any performance advantages this hides the true nature of what is happening here. As it looks like you are giving a list of some objects.

Comment: Evidence for it being faster?

Comment: That link seems to indicate it is more efficient to _write_, but I didn't find anything saying that the time complexity is any different via comprehension methods.

Comment: @GL2014 "Besides the syntactic benefit of list comprehensions, they are often as fast or faster than equivalent use of map."

Answer (score 27):

Well, you could use `map` ([docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)):

```
map(self.queryQ.put, self.getQueries())
```